# Disabled Enter key in save image dialog sometimes in firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox

When I select `Save Image As ...` from <kbd>Right Click</kbd> context menu, `Save Image` window dialog shows. After I type my 'File Name' I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save it. Suddenly (sometimes) I see that nothing happen, then by repeating to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> sometimes it saves, and sometimes after some pressings, So I try to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to save it and it saves the image and also it don't do anything sometimes. Then I press `Save` button by my mouse at end and it always works !!!!

Why it is not working sometiome ?

> **Note** :
>   Most of those sometimes are when many tabs of firefox are open and many of them are loading.
>   In fact when I go to a site of photo gallery I select many pictures to open new tab, then as soon as one of those tabs stop loading I try to (Save Image As ...) by <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on it and pressing <kbd>v</kbd>.

Comment: Yout "note" contains the answer -- Firefox is busy opening other tabs

Comment: You mean when Firefox is busy, my Enter key will not work ... but what's its relation to a busy Firefox, If I click by mouse it will save !

Comment: The enter key will only work if the correct button has focus.

Comment: ... and when in a form like `Save As Image` it is default button (i. default button is a button that user can click it by pressing enter in any part of a form and it's highlighted usually with a darker border).

Answer (score 2):

It is a known bug in Firefox, see bug description/discussion here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=465511

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Comment: Link is still working, bug is still in newest Firefox.